# Чому ми відкидаємо літеру "ς" наприкінці грецьких імен?

Tags: переклад, власні-назви, запозичені-слова, from-greek, іноземні-імена

Подивіться, будь ласка, на вже створені статті з вікіпедії зі сторінки [Список Давньогрецьких Філософів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%96%D0%B2):

1. [Аркесілай](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9),
2. [Архелай](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84)),
3. [Критолай](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84)),
4. [Аммоній](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B9),
5. [Аполлоній](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%A2%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9),
6. [Кассій](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BD_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84)).

Не можу знайти ані політично-історичних причин (іноді в [романських](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassio_Longino_(retore)) мовах так само зникає літера ς, дуже часто у [болґарській](https://bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD) і сербській (навіть у [сербській латинці](https://sh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasije_Longin_(filozof))) зникає), ані того, чому роблять саме так в українській мові. Маю припущення, що це пішло ще з часів римської імперії, але не маю підтверджень.

Спростуйте або підтвердьте, будь ласка, припущення і розкажіть про те, як цей процес йшов в українській мові.

Comment: Чув що це пов'язано із тим що у латинській мові Називний відмінок має ненульове  закінчення (-ус) яке у деяких мовах традиційно відкидають.

Comment: @Artemix ну ось я таке щось відчуваю і розумію, що аж звідти тягнеться, але хотілося б точніше знати. Бо незрозуміло, чому анґлосакси роблять по-одному, а ми - по-іншому.

Comment: Був період, коли вони вважали латині ідеальною мовою і тягнули звідти не те що речення, а цілі граматичні конструкції. В ті часи, наприклад, у слові "борг" яке писалося det, з'явилося b, ( debt ), бо у латині є слово debitare. Про все це я прочитав у книзі "Mother Tongue", там про стосунки англійської з латиною купа прикладів.

Comment: @Artemix можете вже робити неповну відповідь, думаю. Приймати не буду, але догори клацну.

Comment: У вас питання про українську, а в мене коментарі про англійську ;) Не буду додавати відповідь бо треба всі факти пропрацювати більш детально.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У грецькій мові кінцева «ς» є лише частиною відмінкових закінчень певних відмінків (зокрема закінчення «ος» називного відмінка [іменників другої відміни давньогрецької](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_grammar_(tables)#Second-declension_suffixes) та відповідних іменників у [сучасній грецькій](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Greek_grammar#Declensions)). В інших відмінках, в тому числі і кличному, оце «ς», як правило, відпадає.

Називний: Архела**ос** / Αρχέλα**ος**, Александр**ос** / Αλέξανδρ**ος**.
Кличний: Архела**ο** / Αρχέλα**ο**, Александр**е** / Αλέξανδρ**ε**.

Це лише припущення, але я думаю, що саме це і є причиною зникнення кінцевого «с». Греки і самі в інших мовах часто вказують своє ім‘я саме в кличному відмінку. Інакше до них звертатимуться в неприродньому для них називному.

Comment: о, цікаво, дякую.
чи ви знаєте якийсь ресурс грецький на кшталт українського ulif?
можна було б підкріпити відповідь такими посиланнями: http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9

Comment: Я трішки змінив текст. Я не знаю грецької, але, як я бачу з відкритих джерел, оце «ς» зазвичай інтерпретують як частину закінчення (наприклад, «ος»), а не все закінчення; крім того, здається, в деяких відмінах «ς» іноді буває присутнє в інших відмінках; крім того додав самі джерела. Сповідаюся, Ви не проти (якщо Ви проти, Ви маєте право — навіть Вам варто — змінити назад; напишіть, будь ласка мені, якщо Вам не подобається моє редагування і Ви не знаєте, як його скасувати — тоді я відкочу його сам). Я, звісно, міг помилитися, бо не знаю грецької.

Comment: Дякую за редагування :)

Comment: Схожого на ulif сайту для грецької я не знаю, але ось тут є таблиця відмінювання різних грецьких іменників: http://www.greek-language.gr/greekLang/modern_greek/tools/lexica/onomatiko/nouns.html

Comment: В кличному відмінку (Κλητικη) кінцеве «ς» майже всюди відпадає. Але є і винятки, як от χάος чи φως. У власних іменах такі випадки мені не відомі.

Comment: @IraRe, невеличке прохання — коли відповідаєте комусь у коментарях, варто зазначати його (адресата) ім'я через равлик (он як я Ваше тут). За винятком випадків, коли адресуєте коментар саме тому, хто і є автором допису (під яким коментарі) — тоді це необов'язково, бо він у будь-якому разі отримує сповіщення про кожен коментар під його дописом, але в інших випадках варто зазначати адресата, бо інакше він не знатиме, що на його коментар відповіли (якщо, звісно, спеціально не заглядатиме).

Comment: @Sasha, Ira Re дякую вам обом.